# How to handle MouseOverEvent by Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using selenium to automate the web application. I am trying to click on event which is open on mouse over. But **Selenium-IDE** is unable to record that event so how to handle this. So please give me suggestion.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

1.Open http://www.annauniv.edu/
2.Click on the Link ‘Departments’
3.From the ‘Faculty of Civil Engineering’ menu, choose ‘Institute for Ocean Management’

Anna
open    /
clickAndWait    link=Departments
mouseOver   xpath=//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/a/strong
mouseOver   xpath=//*[@id="menuItemHilite30"]

click   xpath=//*[@id="menuItemHilite30"]

Is it satisfying your need?

Comment: Actually i have to click on right side to select that by moving cursor from left to right.so how we can click on right side of that particular strip like.

Comment: This is not just like opening another pane by clicking on a pane

Comment: You can search similar functionality on any public site and then share that with me.. so that your test web site will not become public..:-)